# Hide a specific in-text citation

Tags: bibliographies, apacite

I only want to hide a specific in-text citation but have this citation in the bibliography part. Currently, I'm using `\shortcite` for citation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the citation `<cite>`, you can add

```
\nocite{<cite>}
```

to your document. This would be similar to `\cite{<cite>}` without setting the actual citation within the text. It'll appear in the bibliography.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@article{glashow,
  author       = {Glashow, Sheldon},
  title        = {Partial Symmetries of Weak Interactions},
  journaltitle = {Nucl.~Phys.},
  date         = 1961,
  volume       = 22,
  pages        = {579-588},
}
@article{weinberg,
  author       = {Weinberg, Steven},
  title        = {A Model of Leptons},
  journaltitle = {Phys.~Rev.~Lett.},
  date         = 1967,
  volume       = 19,
  pages        = {1264-1266},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\nocite{glashow}% Include in references, but do not \cite in text.

See~\cite{weinberg}.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```